# How to add custom claim on Jwt Token based on user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jwt, identityserver4

I'm having trouble in adding custom claim (tenant id) to my token. So my program allows users to switch their workspace using tenant id. In order to do that I need to receive the selected Tenant Id and generate new token with the selected tenant id inside the token.

To generate the token first time during login, I used this code

```
var tokenResponse = await httpclient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
                {
                    Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
                    UserName = model.PhoneNumber,
                    Password = model.Password,
                    ClientId = Configuration["ClientInformation:ClientId"],
                    ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientInformation:ClientSecret"]
                });
```

And to generate new token after they login to switch the tenant, I used refresh token.

```
 var tokenResponse = await httpclient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
        {
            Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = Configuration["ClientInformation:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientInformation:ClientSecret"],
            RefreshToken = model.RefreshToken
        });
```

I already seen how profile service receive data using claimsprincipal and thats where I was confused how to insert new value inside the claimsprincipal

So my question is how do I send the selected tenant id to profile service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to do this by saving the tenant id that the user wants to the database and I'm able to get the tenant value using profile service